# Android: no AdMob banners in dual-pane (master/detail)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, master-detail, smartbanner

I am implementing dual-pane (Master/Detail flow), with two different fragments.

I am using **AdMob SmartBanners** in each fragment:

- the Master fragment has a banner at the bottom
- the Detail fragment has a bannner at the top

In **single pane**: the AdMob banners are correctly displayed.
In **dual pane**: the space is taken up by the banners, but no ad is displayed.

Is there any explanation for this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2753860

> **Number of ads per page**
>
> The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one if the ad
>   is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, only
>   one ad should be visible on the screen at a time, and, according to
>   the AdSense program policies, publishers may place no more than 3 ad
>   units on one entire page.